# What's happened to the "href" property in search v7 results?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremap-navigation

The Places API used to have an `href` property that linked to a HERE page for the associated result, so it was easy to use it for attribution. This screenshot shows the field (towards the bottom of the result) for a search result from the places API:
[image: result from places API]

This screenshot shows the result for the same place, but from the search v7 api:
[image]

The `href` property is missing, and there's no replacement. Is there a way to request that the attribute be included in the result? Was the intention for 3rd-party devs to effectively replace the functionality of the `href` by performing a GET request to the `/lookup` endpoint using the provided `id` field of the place?

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific attributes that you are looking for? Basically the idea is that the search V7 provides more info than the Places Api, you can check the examples below:
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=40.7307999,-73.9973085&q=Statue+of+liberty vs [https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=40.7307999,-73.9973085&q=Statue+of+liberty&app_id={}&app_code={}](https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=40.7307999,-73.9973085&q=Statue+of+liberty&app_id=%7B%7D&app_code=%7B%7D)

(if you believe you do need the lookup function you can use this endpoint example: https://lookup.search.hereapi.com/v1/lookup?id=here:pds:place:840dr5r7-9df1349708914ceba912909970598cf7) Let us know if you have any further questions.